# @comments nil while @event.comments works in show partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I cannot figure out why @comments is returning nil when I am attempting to loop through it.  If I use `@event.comments.each do` instead it works just fine.  My current structure is User / Events / Comments.

Comments Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @comment = @event.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Comment Added"
      redirect_to @event
    else 
      flash[:alert] = "Comment Not Added"
      redirect_to @event
    end
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @event.comments
  end

  def destroy
  end

    private

      def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
      end
end
```

Events Controller Show Action:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create,:edit, :update, :show,
                                           :index, :destroy]  
 def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

 private 

    def event_params 
      params.require(:event).permit(:start_date, :start_time, :location,                                            :title, :description, :size, :difficulty,
                                    :activity, :duration)
    end

end
```

Comment Model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user

  validates :body, presence: true

  scope :newest, -> { order("created_at DESC") }
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :created_events, class_name: 'Event', :foreign_key => "creator_id",  
            dependent: :destroy
  has_many :registers, :foreign_key => "attendee_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :attended_events, through: :registers, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :comments, through: :events

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable,            :lockable
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: true }

  validate :validate_name

  def validate_name
    if User.where(email: name).exists?
      errors.add(:name, :invalid)
    end
  end
end
```

Event Model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :latest, -> { order(date: :asc, time: :asc)}

  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :registers, :foreign_key => 'attended_event_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :attendees, through: :registers, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
  validates :location, presence: true
  validates :start_time, presence: true
  validates :start_date, presence: true
  validates :activity, presence: true
  validates :difficulty, presence: true

end
```

and lastly, the comments/_show.html.erb partial:

```
<% if @comments %>
    <span class="results-number color-aqua-show">Comments</span>
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <p class="comments">
        <i class="color-green fa fa-user ride-i"></i>
            <%= comment.user.name %>: <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at).capitalize %> ago
        </p>
      <p>
       <i class="color-aqua fa fa-comment ride-i"></i>
        <%= comment.body %>
      </p>
        <div class="bottom-breaker"></div>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <span class="results-number color-aqua-show">Be the first to comment!</span>
<% end %>
```

Show form from events:

```
<div class="container s-results margin-bottom-50">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">

                <%= render partial: 'comments/show' %>

                <%= render partial: 'comments/form' %>

          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again, if I change @comments in the partial to @events.comments it will recognize that there are comments for the particular event and loop through them.  This has been driving me insane for the better part of 5 hours now.  Thanks.

Comment: what view are you rendering the comments/show partial from?

Comment: you need to add `@comments = @event.comments` in event show action.

Comment: Tried that already.  Yields nil.

Comment: In your `events` controller?

Comment: Yup. Btw Rich I read all your posts about this, and every post I could find for hours.  Was hopeful :) but unable to find a solution.

Comment: Wow really? That's incredible! I'm extending the answer, I pressed tab and enter by accident :/

Comment: can you post the code of partial rending.

Comment: added to original post with some editing to remove quite a bit of code that came prior to it.

Comment: what if you try following
<%= render partial: 'comments/show', collection: @comments %>

Comment: Still not working @Shani

Answer (score 0):

As `Pardeep Saini` said, you need to add `@comments` to `events#show`:

```
def show
    @event = Event.find params[:id]
    @comments = @event.comments
end
```

The problem is that `@comments` is a variable, which needs to be defined. If it isn't defined, then you're going to receive the equivalent of an *undefined* error.

Thus, to fix it, you need to make sure that you're calling a defined variable; either `@comments` (if you've defined it), or `@event.comments`.

---

I think there is a much deeper issue with your structure (from looking at your code).

You'd be better setting it up like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :events do
   resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy] #-> url.com/events/:event_id/comments...
end

#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @event    = Event.find params[:id]
      @comments = @event.comments
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
#app/views/events/show.html.erb
<%= @event.title %>
<%= render @comments %>
<%= render "new_comment" %>

#app/views/events/_comment.html.erb
<%= comment.user.name %>: <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at).capitalize %> ago
<%= comment.body %>

#app/views/events/_new_comment.html.erb
<%= form_for @event.comments.build do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :body %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will make it so that if you browse to `url.com/events/1`, it will output all the event's comments.

The added benefit of this setup is the ability to *create* / *destroy* comments:

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_event

   def create
     @comment = @event.comments.new comment_params
     @comment.user = current_user
     @comment.save
   end

   def destroy
     @comment = @event.comments.find params[:id]
     @comment.destroy
   end

   private

   def comment_params
       params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :user)
   end

   def set_event
       @event = Event.find params[:event_id]
   end
end
```

Comment: Revised answer. It it doesn't work, we should jump into chat to fix it

Comment: still not working.  If I call @event.comments on the comments show partial it works fine.  I basically followed a rails guide how to add comments, but when it came time that I wanted to add pagination to my comments I found out the only way was to use (at)comments, which is where I ran into this problem.

Comment: So to confirm, you've explicitly set `@comments` in your `show` action... and it's still coming back with a `nil` error?

Comment: Correct.  If I set my if statement in the show partial to @event.comments and then <%= (at)comments.each do |comment| ....%> it will return a no method found 'each' nil error.  If I leave it like it is (if (at)comments) it will always skip that and go to the <% else %> portion and display "Be the first to comment".

Comment: Sorry I have to keep adding (at) in place of @ but I can only use the (at) symbol once a comment it seems :(

Comment: It's okay I understand.... hmm - this could either mean that `@comments` is being declared further up the stack (`ApplicationController`?), or you've literally not got any `@event.comments` (which we know is not the case). Have you tried declaring `@comments = Comment.all` or something, to test whether you can actually declare it?

Comment: Yea I have tried @comments = Comment.all and gotten nothing back (still nil)

Comment: Okay so it means there's a problem declaring `@comments`. Can you try setting another var `@commentable = Comment.all` and then `@commentable.each` to see if that works?

Comment: Did it and it throws a undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass still if I put @events.comment under the if.  If I do instead (at)commentable it still just skips over it.  Wish I could jump into chat but don't have enough street cred where SO will allow it yet.

Comment: event_comment 
                         
                         GET    /events/new(.:format)                    events#new
                         GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)               events#edit
                         GET    /events/:id(.:format)                    events#show
                         PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)                    events#update

Comment: Thanks - what does it show in your console http://i.imgur.com/OpBZPVI.png ? It should says `loading EventsController#show as HTML`

Comment: Could an issue be that I reset my database and the id in the comments model is now starting over at 12 vs 1?

Comment: Well I don't see why that would prevent `@comments` from loading, where `@event.comments` does. Maybe try restarting your server?

Comment: Didn't help.  I didn't think it would matter either with the database.  The server responds with a 500 error

Comment: Wow okay. can you go to chat on this, or don't you have that facility yet?

Comment: See if you can join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/94697/test?tab=general

Comment: Wont let me chat I'm afraid.  I hate polluting this thread with endless comments as well :(

Comment: .deleted for privacy issues*

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.  It was a very dumb error where I had show listed twice in my events controller.  The bottom one was over riding the top.